# Changing max length value of textbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, gridview

Some value are returned to ajax from C#.
I need to bind those values to GridView. 
And everything's works ok but only difference is this value:
$("span", row).eq(4).html(this.MaxNoPlaces); needs to be bind to MaxLenght property of textbox instead of value.

I think I need to use this attr('maxlength') instead of html but I don't know how.
Can someone help me with this ?

Thanks in advance!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on('click', ".myBtn", function () {

                header = $(this).closest('tr').find('.ObjekatID').text()
                console.log(header);


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Administration.aspx/GetRequest",
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'header2': header2}),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var row = $("[id*=grdDemo] tr:last-child").clone(true);
                    $("[id*=grdDemo] tr").not($("[id*=grdDemo] tr:first-child")).remove();
                    //  alert($("[id*=grdDemo]").html());
                    var count = 1;
                        $.each(data.d, function () {
                            $("span", row).eq(0).html(this.ObjectID);
                            $("span", row).eq(1).html(this.ObjectName);
                            $("span", row).eq(2).html(this.ObjectValue);
                            $("span", row).eq(3).html(this.ObjectTypeID);

                            $("span", row).eq(4).html(this.MaxNoPlaces);

                            $("[id*=grdDemo] tbody").append(row);
                            console.log(row);
                            if (count == 1 || (count % 2 != 0)) {
                                $(row).css("background-color", "rgb(193, 212, 248)");
                            }
                            else {
                                $(row).css("background-color", "white");
                            }
                            count = count + 1;
                            row = $("[id*=grdDemo] tr:last-child").clone(true);

                        });


                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("Not Saved!");
               }

            });

        });
```

Comment: Just to make sure, are you asking how to set the attribute "maxlength" with the value of this.MaxNoPlaces?

Comment: Yes that correct !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
 $("span", row).eq(4).attr("maxlength",this.MaxNoPlaces);
```

Source: https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Just FYI `prop()` is more appropriate for this.